# FTP Jar file from share path on windows to IFS location in AS400?

Tags: shell, python-3.x, ftp, ibm-midrange

I am looking for an **approach / design** through which i want to **automate the process of FTP from windows location to IFS location present on AS400 environment** when ever there is a new file added to windows path.

## Below is the approach I thought, Please refine it if needed.

1. We have an option `WRKJOBSCDE`through which we can run a CL program in a     scheduled threshold of 1hr.
2. To write a CL program which invokes a script(pyton/shell) to talk to windows location(***say X:drive having its IP as xx.xxx.xx.xx***).
3. Shell script has to search for latest file in the location X:drive and FTP that jar(of size 5mb max) to IFS location(***say /usr/dta/ydrive***) on AS400 machine.
4. Thus, CL program we invoked in STEP2 has to mail to me using `SNDDST`the list of all the jars ftp'd by the scheduler job that runs every 1 hr in STEP1.

> All I am new to CL programming/RPGLE . Please help me with some
>   learning stuff and also design of such concepts.

Comment: If you can find something to monitor the windows folder you could trigger an ftp session to the IBM i (As/400) that can issue a cmd to call your CL program.:
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/eOtlly__H8E

Just make sure that you qualify the call to your CL with the library it's in, then set the library list if needed as the first step in the CL (ADDLIBLE, etc).

Comment: Is there a reason the Windows location can't be reached through the /QNTC file system? Is FTP actually needed?

Comment: @user2338816 QNTC will it be defaully installed in as part of package or need to be configured separately?

Comment: The /QNTC file system is default-installed. You can see it with WRKLNK '/QNTC' and note that quotes are needed on a command line because of the "/" in the parameter. If you don't see the Windows server in the list, try MKDIR '/QNTC/{serverIPAddress}'. Authentication may need new question.

Comment: @user2338816 here is the separate question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116060/how-to-get-authentication-for-qntc-windows-share-drive-ip-in-as400) . Please could you provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like the one provided by Scott Klement at https://www.scottklement.com/ftpapi/ to roll your own automation client. It was designed to be used from RPG, and is easy to use. From there it is a simple task to:

1. retrieve a list of files in the directory
2. parse the list to retrieve file timestamps
3. get any files with a timestamp later than the last successful run

Answer (score 0):

The CL command RUNRMTCMD can be used to invoke a command on a PC running a rexec() client.  iSeries Access for Windows offers such a client, and there are others available.  With the iSeries client, the output of the PC command is placed in a spool file on the AS/400, which should contain the results of the FTP session.

You can copy the spool file to a file using the CPYSPLF command and SNDDST it to yourself, but I am not sure the contents will be converted from EBCDIC to ASCII.

Check out Easy400.net for the MMAIL programs developed by Giovanni Perotti.  This package includes an EMAILSPL command to email a spool file.  I believe you will need to pay $50 for the download.

I think you are on the right track, but the are a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn to program windows. [dotnet filewatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)  Out of scope for a complete answer.  All of the other solutions seem to be polling solutions "Are we there yet?"  "No were not there."