# How to get authentication for /QNTC/{windows Share drive IP} in AS400?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, ftp, ibm-midrange

I am trying to sync the share drive content say X:(IP)of windows , and access the contents of share drive X: from AS400 terminal using `WRKLNK '/qntc/{IPADDRESS}'` .

As per the forum [FTP Jar file from share path on windows to IFS location in AS400?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044560/ftp-jar-file-from-share-path-on-windows-to-ifs-location-in-as400) the authentication of `MKDIR '/QNTC/{IPADDRESS}'` require separate question . So please provide solutions.

Comment: I voted you down for the stupid answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late response. Time of year and other stuff have been very distracting.

What are the OS versions of IBM i and Windows? As Windows changes between releases, networking also changes. Both ends need to maintain compatible networking levels. Other elements can also be important, but which questions can depend on the OS releases.

For perhaps the simplest approach, an IBM i user profile may be set with a password and a same-named user can be created on the Windows system with the same password. Password rules at their simplest would have 10-character maximum length on IBM i and would be all upper-case. The Windows password should match upper-case, but all lower-case also works most often. The Windows user should be created as a local machine (not domain) user.

A job on IBM i would run under the matching user. That might be due to logging on as that user, running a SBMJOB that specifies that user or using one of the security APIs to switch the job temporarily to that user while the connection is used.

From that basic level, a couple more complex (and more secure) methods are possible. All will be easier if the simplest is already working. There might be PTFs or configuration changes needed to get Windows and IBM i working together, and those will be easier to determine before looking for more secure connections.

Nowadays, it can be better to leave Windows networking behind and start using NFS instead. That means ignoring /QNTC and making sure that NFS is installed and active on the Windows system. It can also mean that management of user uids and guids needs to be started. Few AS/400s and later systems have paid any attention to those, but the time might have arrived to get started.

Comment: Don't start an answer with a question.  This isn't a writing class.

Comment: @danny117 Such Qs can be edited out if the OP clarifies, and replaced w/relevant detail. E.g., V5R4 intro'd the threaded file server, so some connection handling changes and more complex methods can need to know. And if it's not a writing class, it needs no writing advice.